# How to search an HTML webpage for certain strings and style them with Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, search, include

I need to search an HTML web page document for 2 separate strings. In this example, I am looking through patents for author names. I need to find those names, replace them with my own string, and color them any color.

I have put the entire list of strings with the names in a NodeList. And I need to somehow use the Node.textContent property to get the text (string) from the element. Then I need to use the nice string includes() method to see if the names contain both "Bob" and "Beb".

But I cannot seem to get anywhere with that, and I cannot find a clear guild explaining how to use those.

Comment: I am really a beginner at JavaScript, so my question does not make much sense. But if you have any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Resource https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/11/javascript-search-text-html-page/ it should be what your looking for but maybe post the code so I can look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can query a Document for text but if you mark it with an id or class you can use 
`getElementById()` or `getElementsByClassName()` and then add classes by using [.setAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) and in your CSS file you can preset the class to have a different color background or whatever. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a great place to learn the syntax for anything, same goes for [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/).

Comment: After getting the hang of Javascript, you can try learning about [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) which is a very powerful and useful JS library. For example, your code in JS like this: `document.getElementById('someId').style.color('lightred')` would be like this in jQuery: `$('#someId').css('color', 'lightred')`.